# I need to run a JQuery method when an attribute contains a certain value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to run a method if the "name" attribute contains the word "test". I believe that I am using an incorrect syntax.

```
if($("input[name*='test']")) {
   alert('found!'); //Do Something
}
```

The HTML I am using is

```
<input name="test" type="text">
```

Comment: Why do you believe your syntax is incorrect?

Comment: Why don't you just use `document.querySelector("input[name*='test']")` which will return `null` if it doesn't exist?

Comment: @j08691 Because I plan on using a few conditions that I would like to bundle together  on click If input value is test1 {do something} if input value is test 2 {do  something} and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specified what is the exact problem with your code, but there's an obvious problem with the way your are testing your selector result.

`$("input[name*='test']")` will always return a jquery object even if there's no match for the specified selector.  In order to validate if the selector has a match, you should check using the `length` property:

```
if($("input[name*='test']").length) {
    alert('found!');
}
```

Comment: That's what I was missing! Thanks so much! Very helpful